# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class, find which dependency is missing

Tags: java, gradle, classnotfoundexception

I am facing **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.tobris.meta.loader.XMLViews** the error doesn't tell to much. is there a way to extend the error and see what dependency is missing?

these are the imports from **XMLViews.java**

```
import javax.annotation.Nullable;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.namespace.NamespaceContext;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.validation.Schema;
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
```

and these are the dependencies from my **gradle.build**

```
    implementation "com.google.guava:guava:28.1-jre"
    implementation "com.opencsv:opencsv:3.9"
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-csv:1.9.0'
    implementation "gradle.plugin.nl.javadude.gradle.plugins:license-gradle-plugin:0.14.0"
    implementation "org.yaml:snakeyaml:
    
    implementation "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.6.1.Final"
    implementation "org.hibernate:hibernate-hikaricp:5.6.1.Final"
    implementation "org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.4.1.Final"
    implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-jcache:5.6.1.Final'
    
    implementation 'com.github.ben-manes.caffeine:jcache:2.6.2'
    
    implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:5.6.1.Final'
    implementation "org.hibernate:hibernate-search-orm:5.7.0.Final"
    
    implementation "gradle.plugin.nl.javadude.gradle.plugins:license-gradle-plugin:0.14.0"
    
    implementation  "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.36"
    implementation "org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.36"
    implementation "org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.36"
    implementation "org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:1.7.36"
    implementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.3.0-alpha14'
    implementation 'commons-cli:commons-cli:1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.inject:guice:4.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.inject.extensions:guice-servlet:4.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.inject.extensions:guice-persist:4.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.inject.extensions:guice-multibindings:4.2.2'
    implementation 'org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxrs:3.15.1.Final'
    implementation 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core:8.5.13'
    implementation 'org.apache.shiro:shiro-guice:1.8.0'
    
    implementation 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1'  
    implementation 'javax.xml.parsers:jaxp-api:1.4.5'
    
    implementation "javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0"
    implementation "javax.servlet.jsp:javax.servlet.jsp-api:2.3.1"
    implementation 'javax.validation:validation-api:2.0.1.Final'
    
    implementation 'org.eclipse.birt.runtime:org.eclipse.birt.runtime:4.5.0a'
```

Comment: try with the command line and add `--debug` this should give more details about the error.

Comment: debug doesn't give to much intel

**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.tobris.meta.loader.XMLViews
com.tobris.meta.loader.ViewLoader.importView(ViewLoader.java:270)
com.tobris.meta.loader.ViewLoader.createDefaults(ViewLoader.java:794
com.tobris.meta.loader.ViewLoader.importDefault(ViewLoader.java:780)
com.tobris.meta.loader.ViewLoader.doLast(ViewLoader.java:134)
com.google.inject.persist.jpa.JpaLocalTxnInterceptor.invoke(JpaLocalTxnInterceptor.java:64)
com.tobris.meta.loader.ModuleManager.lambda$null$4(ModuleManager.java:136)**

Comment: Can you share the ModuleManager.java line 136 ? maybe update the question if you can,
and this is not a missing dependency issue i guess.

Comment: "Could not initialize" simply means some class's static initializer threw an exception. It's possible that exception is itself a NoClassDefFoundError that _does not_ have a message indicating initialization failed (which is the one that indicates: You're missing a dependency), but you didn't paste anything about a NCDFE. Conclusion: You pulled the idea that a dep is missing out of your left nostril, as far as we can tell: I think you have misunderstood the error. A bit logical; NCDFErr is a weird choice by the JVM. There shuold be a cause, that will explain what went wrong.

Comment: **moduleManager.java line 136** 
`newlyInstalledModules.forEach(m -> viewLoader.doLast(m, update));`

`
protected void doLast(Module module, boolean update) {
    // generate default views
    importDefault(module);
`
`final String xml = createDefaults(module, klass);`

`  private String createDefaults(Module module, final Class<?> klass) {
    List<AbstractView> views = createDefaults(klass);
    for (AbstractView view : views) {
      importView(view, module, false, null, 10);
    }
    return XMLViews.toXml(views, false);
  }`

Comment: I was changing the dependencies while that error happened that's why I am suspecting that.